# Stuck on this definite integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've been trying to solve the following definite integral, but unable to make any progress.

$$\int_{-5}^{-2}\frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} dx+\int_{1/6}^{1/3}\frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} dx + \int_{6/5}^{3/2}\frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} dx $$

The only thing I could figure out was the value of the function being integrated is the same at -5, 1/6, and 6/5. Also, it's the same at -2, 1/3, and 3/2. Not sure how this would help though.

Unable to think of any other definite integral property. Also, indefinite integration might become too lengthy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not then three times the first integral (for example)?

Comment: no, why would that be the case?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you. You said that if $f(x)=\frac{(x^2-x)^2}{(x^3-3x+1)^2}$ and $F(x)$ is such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ then $F(-5)=F(\frac{1}{6})=F(\frac{6}{5})$ and $F(-2)=F(\frac{1}{3})=F(\frac{3}{2})$, am I right?

Comment: @AleTolcachier Just because the endpoints of the integrals are equal it doesn't mean the three integrals themselves are equal.  You can see in my answer that the 3 integrals are indeed not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathcal{I}=\underbrace{\int_{-5}^{-2}\frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int_{1/6}^{1/3}\frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x}_{I_2} + \underbrace{\int_{6/5}^{3/2}\frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x}_{I_3} $$

We will use the substitution $u=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $I_1$ and $u=1-\frac{1}{x}$ for $I_3$ so that all three integrals have the same bounds as $I_2$:
\begin{align*}
I_1 &= \int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {x^2(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
I_3 &=\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x-1)^2(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
\end{align*}
Now, rewrite $\mathcal{I}$ as:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}=I_1+I_2+I_3&=\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\right)\frac{(x^2 - x)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{(x^2 - x+1)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align*}
Now, I will present the evaluation of the previous integral using Ostrogradsky's Method.  There is probably an easy substitution or easier approach, but this method will work.
You can find a thorough explanation of Ostrogradsky's Method [here](http://www.nabla.hr/CL-IndefIntegralB2.htm).
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{(x^2 - x+1)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x &= \frac{Ax^2+Bx+C} {x^3 - 3 x + 1} +\int \frac{Dx^2+Ex+F} {x^3 - 3 x + 1} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(\int \frac{(x^2 - x+1)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x \right) &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C} {x^3 - 3 x + 1} +\int \frac{Dx^2+Ex+F} {x^3 - 3 x + 1} \; \mathrm{d}x \right)\\
\frac{(x^2 - x+1)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2}  &= -\frac{Ax^4+2Bx^3+(3A+3C)x^2-2Ax-3C}{\left(x^3-3x+1\right)^2} +\frac{Dx^2+Ex+F} {x^3 - 3 x + 1} \\
(x^2 - x+1)^2 &= Dx^5+(E-A)x^4+(F-3D-2B)x^3+(D-3E-3C-3A)x^2 \\
& \quad +(E-3F+2A)x+(B+3C) \\
\end{align*}
Here we can set up a system of equations to solve for $A,B, C,D,E, \text{ and }F$:
\begin{align*}
D&=0\\
E-A&=1\\
F-3D-2B&=-2\\
-3A-3C+D-3E&=3\\
2A-3F+E&=-2\\
B+3C&=1\\
\end{align*}
Which yields $A=-1$, $B=1$, $C=0$, $D=0$, $E=0$, and $F=0$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I} &= \int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{(x^2 - x+1)^2} {(x^3 - 3 x + 1)^2} \; \mathrm{d}x = \frac{-x^2+x+0} {x^3 - 3 x + 1}\bigg \rvert_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}}  +\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{0x^2+0x+0} {x^3 - 3 x + 1} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{x-x^2}{x^3-3x+1} \bigg \rvert_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{624}{109}} \\
\end{align*}

You can check this answer by using some computing software (I used Wolfram) to calculate $I_1$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%28x%5E2-x%29%5E2%2F%28x%5E3-3x%2B1%29%5E2%20dx%20from%20-5%20to%20-2) to be $\approx 4.41392$, $I_2$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%28x%5E2-x%29%5E2%2F%28x%5E3-3x%2B1%29%5E2%20dx%20from%201%2F6%20to%201%2F3) to be $\approx 0.419169$, and lastly $I_3$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%28x%5E2-x%29%5E2%2F%28x%5E3-3x%2B1%29%5E2%20dx%20from%206%2F5%20to%203%2F2) to be $\approx 0.891683$; and so $\mathcal{I} \approx 4.41392+0.419169+0.891683 = 5.724772$ and $\frac{624}{109} \approx 5.72477064$.

Comment: Any reason why we chose to change the limits to match the I2 and not I1 or I3? Also, what happens at the last step?

Comment: @yomayne No, I just chose to march $I_2$.  You could of done it differently.